# matlab consecutive of ones in a cell

Tags: matlab

A column of a cell array contains some 0s and 1s.

```
A=[0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0];
```

I want to have a result contains just the indices of all ones in a way that all consecutive ones come together in a cell:

```
result = 
3    4    5    6
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach with `diff`, `find` & `mat2cell` -

```
%// Find lengths of islands of nonzeros
dfA = diff([0 A 0])                     
lens = find(dfA==-1) - find(dfA==1)

%// Get corresponding indices for each element
vals = A.*(1:numel(A))

%// Pack them up into cells based on the runlengths
out = mat2cell( vals(A==1) , 1 , lens )
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0
>> celldisp(out)
out{1} =
     1
out{2} =
     5     6     7     8
out{3} =
    12    13
```

Comment: Well done I think I misunderstood the question haha +1

Comment: @Benoit_11 haha happens I guess! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the question you refers to "cellarray" while in the code privided the varaible "A" is an array.
Moreover, the "result" provided seems not in line with the content of the array "A": the index of the first "1" is "2" not "3".

If the variable to work with is actually an array, the indexes of the "1" can be easly found using the built-in function "find".